Rigidity of a subscheme
I would like to ask whether there is a connection between the rigidity of an exceptional curve described by $E^2=-1$ and the concept 'rigidity' in the deformation theory. Roughly I am looking for some conceptual explanation about infinitesimal deformations, as I only briefly encountered them in Hartshorne's book (Algebraic Geometry). Let me write $D=k[t]/t^2$, and make questions more precise.

He uses the terminology 'no infinitesimal deformation' to defining rigid varieties, which I guess to mean 'no nontrivial infinitesimal deformation', where trivial one is given by idealization of structure sheaf: $(a,b)\cdot (c,d) = (ac, ad+bc)$.

He also defines 'infinitesimal deformation as a subscheme' of $Y\subset X$ as a closed subscheme of $Y'\subset X\times_k D$ with some properties. Does this allows more freedom to deform, perhaps by allowing the use of normal directions?

I wonder if $E^2=-1$ can be explained in this way. We say that $E$ cannot be moved to properly intersect with $E$. This is under linear equivalence, so surely a flat family (I'm not sure). Hence $E^2=-1$ implies that $E$ cannot have an infinitesimal deformation as a subvariety of $\tilde{X}$.

But it looks like even trivial deformation should not exists in above case. I don't know how to explain this. My current understanding (from Wikipedia) of trivial deformation is that an infinitesimal deformation coming from a trivial family $X\times T\to T$, so in particular all fibres are isomorphic. E.g. $\mathbb{P}^1$ is rigid, which is the only genus $0$ curve, while there are many non-isomorphic elliptic curves.

Finally, is the converse of 3 true? By studying infintesimal deformations, can we do something called 'moving lemma' in intersection theory? Actually this was the first question that came to mind, but now it looks there is too much gap (even if, at least, 3 is true).


A calculation I did: for an exceptional curve $E\simeq\mathbb{P}^1\subset \tilde{X}$, the normal bundle (also for general blowing ups) is $\mathcal{O}_E(-1)$ so it has no (nontrivial?) infinitesimal deformation as a closed subscheme of $\tilde{X}$. However $\mathbb{P}^1\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ as a hyperplane has normal bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$, so can be deformed? (Maybe into conics?)
Any correction and explanation of above points would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

What exactly is your question here? What is the meaning of ‘more freedom to deform’? The trivial deformation always exists. A P^1 in P^2 embedded as a line will only deform to other lines, and not conics.

@CraniumClamp, I am asking for the correction or confirmation of five points I thought of. Since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is rigid itself, but $\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(1)) \ne 0$ gives more infinitesimal deformations as a line in a plane, I wondered how this is possible. Is it just because we count embeddings, not up to isomorphisms?

The deformations of a P^1 embedded as a closed subscheme of P^2 are classified by global sections of the normal bundle. Each such deformation also gives an abstract deformation of the P^1 by forgetting the embedding. That’s trivial because P^1 is rigid.

@CraniumClamp Thank you, those explain them. (Now it looks obvious, but it was confusing without concrete referneces.) Do you have any idea for 3 or 5?
